# "blue is not a valid ColorBrewer code" Error while creating Choropleth using Folium (Python)

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science, folium

I am trying to create a choropleth using Folium, however I am running to the error mentioned above. 
Here is my dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

Here is my GeoJSON snippet for 'MISSION' district:

```
...{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID": 4,
      "DISTRICT": "MISSION",
      "COMPANY": "D"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [...
```

Here is my attempt at creating the choropleth:

```
world_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=world_geo,
    name='choropleth',
    data=dc,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
#     color='YlOrRd',
#     fill_opacity=0.7,
#     line_opacity=0.5
    )
```

Here is the error that it throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-80d58334d627> in <module>
      4     data=dc,
      5     columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'],
----> 6     key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
      7 #     color='YlOrRd',
      8 #     fill_opacity=0.7,

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/folium.py in choropleth(self, *args, **kwargs)
    416         )
    417         from folium.features import Choropleth
--> 418         self.add_child(Choropleth(*args, **kwargs))
    419 
    420     def keep_in_front(self, *args):

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1046         self._name = 'Choropleth'
   1047 
-> 1048         if data is not None and not color_brewer(fill_color):
   1049             raise ValueError('Please pass a valid color brewer code to '
   1050                              'fill_local. See docstring for valid codes.')

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/branca/utilities.py in color_brewer(color_code, n)
    147 
    148     if base_code not in core_schemes:
--> 149         raise ValueError(base_code + ' is not a valid ColorBrewer code')
    150 
    151     try:

ValueError: blue is not a valid ColorBrewer code
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see there is no `blue` in the [base codes](https://github.com/python-visualization/branca/blob/master/branca/scheme_base_codes.json), but the default param for `fill_color` in [folium.features.Choropleth](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/4a7532d34c22532167d128dddd07b1578ed08f37/folium/features.py#L1129) is 'blue'.

Try to change it to something like `Blues` by adding the `fill_color = "Blues"` param when you create the choropleth and see if something changes

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks... Turns out fill_color and color are two different attributes.